# How to reload child view object completely in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, sunburst-diagram

I have a 2 `ViewObjects` A and B. each connected with a `ViewLink`. I have shuttled the ViewLink in the `ApplicationModule`. So B comes under A in DataControl.

I have a `Sunburst` graph component using this instance. My requirement is to change the ViewObject Query at runtime. This works fine. But the graph is not getting refreshed for the level 2. Only Level 1 getting refreshed.

ie; A is only getting refreshed.

**How to refresh B (Or the view link) ?**

Answer (score 0):

This sounds weird since view link usually get refreshed together automatically.

Your requirement is change the VO query at runtime. I don't have much details on your implementation, how would you manage to do this? Through an ApplicationModule method ? or some VO manipulation. Anyway, after you update a query, you need to do an executeQuery() right?

A possible way to solve your problem is to call B.executeQuery() after you update A's query.

Comment: Yes, That is all done. But only the Parent component is refreshing and the child remains same.

Comment: I have a doubt in the `viewlink` part. We will drop the `viewlink` and change the VO query and recreate the `viewlink` programmatically.  Because we cant change the query since having a `viewlink`. Is there any alternatives ?